# Open function or stored procedure in new query window using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for something fairly straightforward. When I'm writing a stored procedure as shown here, I would like to open 'objects' ( functions, stored procedures) by clicking them and then using a shortcut key.

The scenario :

1. Select the relevant function or stored procedure in the currently open stored procedure

   [image]
2. Press a shortcut key, that opens this function or stored procedure inside a new query. Goal :

   [image]

I looked at several other posts regarding the topic, couldn't find this.

I also tried
[SQL Server Search Database Objects "on the fly" with Native SSMS Functionality / SSMS Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877266/sql-server-search-database-objects-on-the-fly-with-native-ssms-functionality)

Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks

Comment: RedGate SQL Prompt is already doing it

Comment: There is no built in functionality for this.

Comment: You need a 3rd party tool. I use SQLPrompt for this and much more - hover mouse over text to get immediate object definitions, format sql with custom rules, populate parameters etc; it saves a huge amount of time but is pricey, you can download the Redgate toolbelt and try it out - well worth your IT dept to invest however. Maybe Microsoft might add cool features like this to ADF, in about 10 years when they've implemented the existing SSMS functionality.

Comment: Just an aside ... you can trim that function down to RETURN ( select ... )

Comment: Azure Data Studio that comes bundled with SSMS these days, does this

Comment: I would also recommend RedGate SQL Search.  Where you can paste that into a search bar and double click to quick-navigate to the item in object explorer>

Comment: Back when i used ssms, you could bind keyboard commands to an sql command, i usually had F2 bound to: `exec sp_helptext` so when you selected a proc and pressed F2, you got it's definition in the message box and copypasted it to new window.